# output a column group by another columns in shell

Tags: linux, shell, awk, group, columns

Thanks in advance!

I have a file with 3 columns like this:

```
serv1   red     group1
serv1   black   group1
serv1   orange  group1
serv1   red     group2
serv1   orange  group2
serv1   red     group3
serv1   black   group3
serv1   orange  group3
serv2   orange  group1
serv2   red     group2
serv2   orange  group2
serv2   red     group3
serv2   black   group3
serv2   orange  group3
serv3   orange  group1
serv3   red     group1
```

And I would show like this:

```
serv1   group1  red black   orange
serv1   group2  red orange
serv1   group3  red black   orange
serv2   group1  orange
serv2   group2  red orange
serv2   group3  red black   orange
serv3   group1  orange  red
```

If I a try to group only by 1st with the next code, I show good, but I can´t doing grouping wtit more than one:

```
awk '{ V_GRUPO[$1]= (V_GRUPO[$1]==""?"":V_GRUPO[$1] OFS) $2 }END  { for(x in V_GRUPO) print x, V_GRUPO[x] }' file.txt
```

```
serv1   red black   orange red  orange  red black   orange
serv2   orange  red orange  red black   orange
serv3   orange  red
```

¿how could I do it???

Thanks!!

Comment: It's unclear what the delimiter between the fields is in your input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script, script-file.awk :

```bash
{
    k = $1 OFS $3
    a[k] = (k in a ? a[k] OFS : "" ) $2
}
END{
    for(key in a){
        print key, a[key]
    }
}
```

Then run :

```bash
awk -f script-file.awk input
```

- `a[k]` is an array using the key `k = $1 OFS $3`
- `OFS` is the Output Field Separator
- `?` is a conditional (`test ? true : false`)
- `for(key in a)` for each key

---

This may not be sorted, so if you need it sorted pipe it :

```bash
awk -f script-file.awk input | sort
```

Comment: In contrast to the code in the question you use the `?`...`:` operator like `if`...`else`. I suggest `a[$1 OFS $3] = ( a[$1 OFS $3] ? a[$1 OFS $3] OFS : "" ) $2` or `i = $1 OFS $3; a[i] = ( a[i] ? a[i] OFS : "" ) $2` similar to the question.

Comment: @Bodo You're totally right, I added it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the fields in the input are delimited by multiple spaces (a sort of "pretty printed tabular" format) and that you want to collapse the entries in the second field, based on the other two fields, into a space-delimited list:

```bash
$ mlr --pprint -N nest --ivar ' ' -f 2 then reorder -f 1,3,2 file
serv1 group1 red black orange
serv1 group2 red orange
serv1 group3 red black orange
serv2 group1 orange
serv2 group2 red orange
serv2 group3 red black orange
serv3 group1 orange red
```

This does the collapsing and the reordering of the original fields using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`).

If the data is tab-delimited (TSV), and you want tab-delimited output, then change `--pprint` into `--tsv`.  Would you want a different delimiter for the collapsed list of data, then change `--ivar ' '` into e.g. `--ivar ';'` (to use `;`).

For example, with tab-delimited input and output, with `;` as the list delimiter:

```bash
$ mlr --tsv -N nest --ivar ';' -f 2 then reorder -f 1,3,2 file
serv1   group1  red;black;orange
serv1   group2  red;orange
serv1   group3  red;black;orange
serv2   group1  orange
serv2   group2  red;orange
serv2   group3  red;black;orange
serv3   group1  orange;red
```

Another example, reading TSV input, adding labels to each field, using these labels instead of numerical fields, and producing pretty-printed tabular output:

```bash
$ mlr --itsv --implicit-csv-header --opprint --barred label Server,Colour,Group then nest --ivar ';' -f Colour then reorder -f Server,Group,Colour file
+--------+--------+------------------+
| Server | Group  | Colour           |
+--------+--------+------------------+
| serv1  | group1 | red;black;orange |
| serv1  | group2 | red;orange       |
| serv1  | group3 | red;black;orange |
| serv2  | group1 | orange           |
| serv2  | group2 | red;orange       |
| serv2  | group3 | red;black;orange |
| serv3  | group1 | orange;red       |
+--------+--------+------------------+
```

Comment: thanks! But I can`t install mlr in the machine...I need to do with awk or similar tools

Comment: @iam I can't help you with that, other than to say that you don't have to be root to install Miller.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is already sorted by your 2 key fields, this will only save the values for 1 key pair at a time in memory, using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    { key = $1 OFS $3 }
    key != prev { if (NR>1) print vals; prev=vals=key }
    { vals = vals OFS $2 }
    END { print vals }
' file
serv1 group1 red black orange
serv1 group2 red orange
serv1 group3 red black orange
serv2 group1 orange
serv2 group2 red orange
serv2 group3 red black orange
serv3 group1 orange red
```

If your real input isn't already sorted as your sample input is then just sort it first:

```
sort -b -k1,1 -k3,3 file | awk '...'
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding you correctly, in the example I gave at the beginning( awk '{ V_GRUPO[$1]= (V_GRUPO[$1]==""?"":V_GRUPO[$1] OFS) $2 }END  { for(x in V_GRUPO) print x, V_GRUPO[x] }' file.txt

 ), it does order me even though the values are not ordered, is it not possible to put a second column? then the solution would be to previously order the data from the file entry?

Comment: Addressing each specific item in your comment: a) "it does order me" - if you mean you get output in some specific order, no `for(x in V_GRUPO)` will produce output in implementation-defined (usually hash) order, if you see some specific order today it's just coincidence. b) "even though the values are not ordered" yes, they are ordered in your posted input. c) "is it not possible to put a second column" - yes my answer does that. d) "the solution would be to previously order..." - yes, just as you already have in your posted sample input.

Answer (score 0):

To collapse a column group by another (or other columns) `datamash` can be used.

```
$ datamash -sW groupby 1,3 collapse 2 --collapse-delimiter ' ' <file
```

About Collapse delimiter from its manual:

```
--collapse-delimiter=x
-c x
Use character X instead of comma to delimit items in a ‘collapse’ or ‘unique’ (aka ‘uniq’) list.
```